# how to instal selenium for python 3.6.8

Tags: python, python-3.x, selenium

I need selenium to test the scheduling of responses in a search engine.
I installed version 3.6.8 of python.
I typed this command on the cmd:

`C: \ Users \ *******> py - 3.6 -m pip install selenium`

and here is what gave:

```
Python 3.6.8 (/ v3.6.8 tags: 3c6b436a57, Dec 23 2018, 23:31:17) [MSC v.1916 32bit (Intel)] on win32
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
```

I thought the installation was complete and I tried to run this code to test:

```
from selenium import webdriver

browser = webdriver.Firefox()
browser.get('http://seleniumhq.org/')
```

here is the error that appeared:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "U:/Python/script.py", line 1, in <module>
    from selenium import webdriver
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'selenium'
```

Can you help me to install the selenium module or to resolve this problem?
Thanks

Comment: How are you launching the script? Are you using PyCharm or something?

Comment: I am using IDLE !

Comment: You could check the installed packages with "pip list", it should appear there

Comment: Package    Version
---------- -------
pip        18.1
setuptools 40.6.2

Comment: Seems that you don't have any package installed or you are using a virtual envirmonment. I would recommend you to develop using PyCharm and then use it with the cmd if you want

Comment: I usually do not use python, it's just to test the query using selenium, otherwise I do not need pycharm or jupyter. Idle will suffice me

Comment: Try to reinstall python then...

Comment: It is not a problem related to python it is rather a positing of proxy, I try to regulate that firstly!

Answer (score 1):

Python 3+ has `pip` already installed.

What `pip` does is add libraries to python. So todo so you need to run the `pip install` in a shell of some sort.

In this case, I used the "Command Prompt":

```
pip install -U selenium
```

You should see something like this:
 [image]

NOTE:

In Linux, you need to use `sudo`:

```
sudo pip install -U selenium
```

---

### Update

Go to [pypi.org](https://pypi.org/project/selenium/#files), Download the wheel (selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl), download it on your PC.

Then run `pip install selenium-3.141.0-py2.py3-none-any.whl`, This should do the trick!

Hope this helps you!

Comment: ```>>> pip install -U selenium
  File "<stdin>", line 1
    pip install -U selenium
              ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax ```

Comment: @RymBoukriba Not in the IDLE! use Command Prompt. are you using windows?

Comment: @MosheSalvin  I'm sorry I misunderstood your question, I'm using the cmd to run these commands

Comment: @RymBoukriba when you use `pip` you don't write `python` before the pip command... Just write pip install... Let me know if you need more help

Comment: That's exactly what I did !

Comment: @RymBoukriba did you copy paste the command in my answer into Command Prompt?

Comment: ```C:\Users\*****>pip install -U selenium
Collecting selenium
  Retrying (Retry(total=4, connect=None, read=None, redirect=None, status=None)) after connection broken by 'ProxyError('Cannot connect to proxy.', OSError('Tunnel connection failed: 407 Proxy Authentication Required',))': /simple/selenium/           Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement selenium (from versions: )
No matching distribution found for selenium```